# How to use filter in Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A model named Post, corresponding to posts table in the db. `Post.find_within_4_days` can get me the last 4 days posts. All my following operation would be based on the past 4 days posts. I would like it to be filtered or defined somewhere, so I can just reference it instead of repeating `Post.find_within_4_days` everywhere. How do I do in Post model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even more flexible:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :within, lambda { |time| where("created_at > ?", Time.zone.now - time }
end

Post.within(4.days)
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using Rails 3, you could use a name scope like this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :within_4_days, where(# however you find your 4 day old posts #)
end
```

You could then use `Post.within_4_days` everywhere.

If you want only the posts of the last 4 days anywhere, you could set up a default scope instead:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope where(# however you find your 4 day old posts #)
end
```

after which (for example) `Post.all` would only return the posts of the last 4 days.

Answer (score 1):

`default_scope` and `scope` are great options for your case,
refer to this [wonderful site](http://api.rubyonrails.org/)